# Cannot close PDFStamper after Setfield

Tags: vb.net, itext

The VB.Net code below works under v 5.3.4 but the .Close statement fails under v5.4.1 and v5.4.1. I can use the same code and switch .dlls to reproduce the problem.

Me.Text in the second line is a textbox containing the path to the file. The file was created with AcroBat 9.5 and it has two form fields named 'NAME' and 'PHONE'.

The itextsharp.dll from the core.zip is added as a reference to the project. At the form level: IMPORTS itextsharp.text and .text.pdf. Thanks!

Could someone verify this and report the bug? Or let me know what I'm doing wrong (besides using WinForms and VB.Net:)?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim newFile As String = Me.Text.Replace(".pdf", "_Out.pdf")

    ''//create w/overwrite copy of the template
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create))

    pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    ''//set form pdfFormFields ' field names are case sensitive
    pdfFormFields.SetField("NAME", "Firstname Lastname")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("PHONE", "805.555.1212")

    ''//report by reading values from completed PDF
    Dim sTmp As String = "Completed: " + pdfFormFields.GetField("NAME") + " " + _
    pdfFormFields.GetField("PHONE")
    MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Finished")

    ''//flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
    ''//to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

    ''//close the pdf
    pdfStamper.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the exception, I suspect you are doing something wrong

Comment: Where is `pdfTemplate` being set and what is it being set to?

Comment: ?ex
{"Cannot access a closed file."}
    System.ObjectDisposedException: {"Cannot access a closed file."}
I may be doing something wrong but the exact code works under an earlier version. See OP. pdfTemplate is a path to my PDF template file. It is being "sent" via the Dim of the PDFStamper - a stream is created and I think flushed to disk at .Close time. (just a guess)